# sub URLs to my website not loading on Linux, Azure and Nginx - 404 not found

Tags: linux, azure, nginx, unix, devops

Can someone please help on what the issue is here.

I have a React web app hosted on Azure Web App. It has been deployed successful.

My problem is, if, for example, I go to the site on `myweb.azurewebsites.net` it loads well. And if I click on a button like the "signin" button it redirects me to `myweb.azurewebsites.net/signin`.

However, if I manually type in `myweb.azurewebsites.net/signin` into the browser, it gives an "Nginx not found" error.

Can someone help on what the issue is. I suspects it's between Azure and/or Nginx.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I didn't add an Nginx conf file and copy it into the Nginx Docker container. When I did that, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx not found 404 error](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-fix-common-nginx-errors) means Nginx can’t find the resources your web browser asks for.

- Check web root directory exists on your server.
- Make sure your website files are stored in the correct directory.

##### To resolve "Nginx not found 404 error", please find below workarounds if helpful:

[**Workaround1:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975285/404-not-found-when-using-nginx-web-server)

> The most likely issue is that you're not telling Nginx to forward
> other requests to the /index.html of your application, which makes it
> so your other pages can't be loaded directly and display a 404 error.
> To fix this, you'll need to ***make a small change to your Nginx
> configuration files**.*

Make sure your `nginx.conf` file as shown below:

```cs
worker_processes 1;
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
sendfile on;
keepalive_timeout 65;

#gzip on;
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
root /home/user_name/Documents/your_proj; # You need to provide here the path of your "index.html" file
index index.html index.htm;
}
}
```

[**Workaround2:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629969/nginx-not-showing-custom-page-not-found-page-in-react-app)

If **Workaround1** does not work, try changing the **`location segment`** as below

```js
location / {

if (!-e $request_filename){

rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
}
}
```

[**Workaround3:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624277/react-app-not-starting-in-azure-app-service?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Configure the startup command on **"Settings** > **General settings** > **Startup Command"**.
Change the path to your build path.

To redirect all queries, use the `--spa` option:

```js
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/client/build --no-daemon --spa
```

[**Workaround4:**](https://serverfault.com/questions/873601/nginx-is-not-found-20-not-a-directory)

In the `nginx.conf` file, try commenting-out the `disable_symlinks on` line or changing it to `disable_symlinks off`.

Comment: thank you @srideviMachavarapu-MT. I discovered that I didn't add an Nginx conf file and copy it into the Nginx Docker container. Not the correct answer in my specific case but leads me to it. When I did that, it works fine.